# Setting user control position

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I'm using an ItemsControl and my elements are all drawn on the top left corner, which create to a gap between the actual position and the mouse position (where my elements should be). Relevant mouse positions are saved in view model.

```
                   <ItemsControl
                        ItemsSource="{Binding OverlayElementsList}"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="2">

                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding ElementName=X, Path=Client.OverlayElement.StartPoint}" />
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding ElementName=Y, Path=Client.OverlayElement.StartPoint}" />
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>


                    <ItemsControl.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type elements:OverlayElement}">
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding View}" />

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.Resources>
```

Here is one of the possible View binded in the ItemsControl.Resources :

```
<UserControl x:Class="Client.ImageOverlayElementView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Genetec.CS.OverlayModule.Client"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ImageOverlayElement}">
    <Grid>
            <Image 
                Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
                Height="{Binding Height}"
                Width="{Binding Width}"
                Canvas.Left="{Binding StartPoint}"
                Canvas.Top="{Binding EndPoint}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties seem to be simply ignored, why ?

Comment: Canvas.Left doesn't affect positioning of an image in a Grid.  it would work in an Image in a Canvas.  Since the *UserControl* is in the grid, place the canvas bindings on the root of your UserControl and see if that works.

Comment: Placing the canvas bindings on the root of the Usercontrol didn't work but replacing the grid by a canvas makes things better, the usercontrol isn't always at the top left corner and can be placed anywhere. There is still a huge gap between the mouse position and the position of the usercontrol though.